# Port forwarding with VPSGet

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, iptables, vps

I bought a domain on GoDaddy but developed the website using Node.js. So, I bought a VPS on VPSGet and deployed the server. I managed to link the domain name to the VPS IP address. However, since my node.js application is running a particular port number I needed to do port forwarding so that www.domain-name.com will redirect to the process and port on the VPS. I tried to configure my firewall as follows

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 7497

COMMIT

*filter
# Allow all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accept all established inbounds connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow all outbounds traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allow  HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere. Here, we use normal ports for http and ssl
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

# Allow http connections to node.js app
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7497 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7525 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2368 -j ACCEPT

# Allow forwarding to port 7497
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7497 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ports for testing
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080:8099 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ports for mobile shell
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 60000:61000 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ssh connections
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 7112 -j ACCEPT

# Allow Ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# Log iptables denied calls
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied:" --log-level 7

# Reject all other outbounds
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A FORWARD -j REJECT

COMMIT
```

However, the redirection is not working. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Please note that I am running a Ubuntu 12.04 on the VPS.
Thanks,
José

Comment: Can you run "ip route list" and verify your external interface IS in fact called "eth0".. Many VPS providers use virtual interfaces.  Mine uses "venet0".  The is the same as on the VPSnet wiki.  You will likely need to adjust the REDIRECT rule to use the correct interface name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create the support request with detailed explanation to vpsget.com ?

Regarding to the wiki

[http://wiki.vpsget.com/index.php/Forward_(redirect/nat)_traffic_with_iptables](http://wiki.vpsget.com/index.php/Forward_%28redirect/nat%29_traffic_with_iptables)

you should use venet0 instead eth0